# Local variable scope breach, C#?

Tags: c#, variables

I got this piece of code,

```
delegate void Printer();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Printer> printers = new List<Printer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            printers.Add(delegate { Console.WriteLine(i); });
        }

        foreach (Printer printer in printers)
        {
            printer();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here the output is '10' for ten times.

The scope of i is with in the for loop. But while we retrieve in out side that we are still getting value from i.

How is it possible?

Comment: [Closing over loop variables considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) discusses this in the context of `foreach` loops, but the same reasoning also stands for `for` loops. Also, you'll note that `foreach` loops have now changed.

Answer (score 2):

You have modified closure. Try this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int ii = i;
        printers.Add(delegate { Console.WriteLine(ii); });
    }
```

When you use in your anonymous method access the the variable in you local scope it creates closure.

Comment: But what about the Scope of i/ii? it is local to for loop.. right?

Comment: Yes but is not modified, in each loop we create new local `ii`.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the delegate is not run until it is called, which happens in the second loop. It then refers to the `i` which was defined within the scope of the first loop, but with it's *current* value - and since the first loop has been completed already, `i` will be 10 each time.

I believe each of the delegates you create are given the same scope as the first loop, if that makes sense. This means that each `i` has it's delegate as it's scope, and since each delegate is defined within the scope of the first loop, each `i` will also have the loop as it's scope, even if the delegate logic is called *outside* that scope, as in your example.

Since `i` is valid throughout / across several iterations of the loop, it gets updated, and is always 10 by the time the delegates get called.

This explains why the following works as a fix:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var localVar = i; // Only valid within a single iteration of the loop!
    printers.Add(delegate { Console.WriteLine(localVar); });
}
```

Comment: But what about the Scope of i? it is local to for loop.. right?

Comment: `i` is captured, so it's scope is somewhat extended. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) - "A variable that is captured will not be garbage-collected until the delegate that references it becomes eligible for garbage collection."

Comment: @Dhana I've updated my answer to provide a little more info.

Answer (score 0):

Each delegate is only invoked in the `foreach`, after the `for` loop. By this time, the variable `i` captured by the closure is already at its final value, viz 10. You can solve like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var cache = i;
    printers.Add(delegate { Console.WriteLine(cache); });
}
```

Comment: But what about the Scope of i/cache? it is local to for loop.. right?

Comment: It's not a scope problem. It is an execution timing problem. Have a look at what @Sweko has unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Let's unroll the loop:

```
int i=0;
printers.Add(delegate { Console.WriteLine(i); })
i=1;
printers.Add(delegate { Console.WriteLine(i); })
...
i=10;
printers.Add(delegate { Console.WriteLine(i); })
```

As you can see the `i` variable is captured within the delegate, and the delegate itself is not run until the loop ends, and the variable has achieved the last value (10).

A simple workaround is to assign the loop variable to a local helper variable

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   var index = i;
   printers.Add(delegate { Console.WriteLine(index); });
}
```

As for the scope issue, any captured variables have their scope (and lifetime) extended. A variable used within a lambda/delegate will not be garbage collected until the delegate itself goes out of scope - which can be a problem for large objects. Specifically, section, 7.15.5.1 of the C# 5 Specification states:

> When an outer variable is referenced by an anonymous function, the
>   outer variable is said to have been captured by the anonymous
>   function. Ordinarily, the lifetime of a local variable is limited to
>   execution of the block or statement with which it is associated
>   (§5.1.7). However, the lifetime of a captured outer variable is
>   extended at least until the delegate or expression tree created from
>   the anonymous function becomes eligible for garbage collection.